# I find a `Object.prototype.inspect` code snippet in graphql/graphql-js repo, what case it will be invoked?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

Recently, I find a code snippet in [graphql/graphql-js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/jsutils/defineToJSON.js#L14), I googled for a while, and I didn't find any useful explanation, are there some special packages will call it?

code snippet as blew:

[image]

--------- Update Question ---------

This is a deprecated way that implement the custom inspection functions on Objects, and the relevant description has removed from the latest docs of Node.js, we can find it in previous docs [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v4.x/api/util.html#util_custom_inspect_function_on_objects) or [Deprecated APIs section](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/deprecations.html#deprecations_dep0079_custom_inspection_function_on_objects_via_inspect) in the latest docs.

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to providing a custom implementation of `util.inspect` as shown in the [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v4.x/api/util.html#util_custom_inspect_function_on_objects). What's not really made clear in the docs is that this also impacts how `console.log` behaves:

```
class Foo {}
Foo.prototype.inspect = () => 'FOO!'
console.log(new Foo()) // prints FOO!
```

However, this method has been [deprecated](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/deprecations.html#deprecations_dep0079_custom_inspection_function_on_objects_via_inspect) in favor of using a symbol:

```
const { inspect } = require('util')
class Foo {}
Foo.prototype[inspect.custom] = () => 'FOO!'
console.log(new Foo()) // prints FOO!
```

Comment: I read that docs, but I didn't find any description about deprecated `inspect` prototype method, util I open your link above, I find out that the description has removed from the latest docs of Node.js.

Comment: Not sure what you mean -- the deprecation is still documented [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/deprecations.html#deprecations_dep0079_custom_inspection_function_on_objects_via_inspect)

Comment: My fault, I mean [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/util.html#util_custom_inspection_functions_on_objects), it removed

Comment: Ok. I fixed the link to point to the older docs that show the deprecated usage.

Comment: great!! appreciate it!!